# Waiting for element load after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, svg, onload

I have a function that loads a SVG Dom from a file. Currently, it creates an `embed` element and places it in the document, then waits for it to load with an `onload` event. Apparently, however, `onload` isn't called for elements placed in the document after the page has loaded. Is there a way that I can register a function to be called after the element has finished loading?

This is what I have:

```
function loadSVG(svgFilename, callback)
{
  // Loads data from an svg file
  // loadSVG(
  //           svgFilename, // The path to the file to load
  //           callback     // The function to be called with the
  //                        // SVG document once it loads.
  //        );            
  var embed = document.createElement("embed");
  embed.src = svgFilename;
  embed.onload = function() // Doesn't get called because page has already loaded
  {
    var doc = embed.getSVGDocument();
    document.getElementById("SVGLoader").removeChild(embed);
    callback(doc);
  };
  document.getElementById("SVGLoader").appendChild(embed);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you put the JavaScript onload event anywhere besides in the body tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/can-you-put-the-javascript-onload-event-anywhere-besides-in-the-body-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant: [How to check if an embedded SVG document is loaded in an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337293/how-to-check-if-an-embedded-svg-document-is-loaded-in-an-html-page)

If you have control over the SVG document, could you not add a script in it that calls a function in the browser window?

Or, as the answer to that question suggested, polling to see if the SVG document has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705218/waiting-for-element-load-after-page-has-loaded/3705364#3705364

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem, I was loading the SVG document in a `div` tag that was hidden with `style="display:none"`. For some reason, the browser didn't load the `embed` when it was in this tag. When I removed the style attribute, the onload event fired the way I expected it to.

Comment: I'd probably reorder the script such that the onload handler is defined before you set 'src', just in case the load happens immidiately. Also you should consider switching to `<object>` instead of `<embed>`.

Comment: Thanks, Erik, I'll consider it.