# chrome getSVGDocument() not work / how to get svg document in a html file in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg

Belows are codes.

Or try this(temporarily): http://ihome.ust.hk/~cs_lyfac/svgQuestion/a.html

When you hit enter it is fine and svgDocument object is alerted. But if you refresh it, it is undefined. Why? Moreover, it is always undefined when in local mode.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Animating SVG</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gear.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#CCAAFF" onload="RotateSVG()">

        <object id="gear" data="gear.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
                width="500" height="500"
                style="position: absolute; top: -250px; left: -250px;">
        </object>

   </body>
</html>
```

and

```
function RotateSVG()
{

    var svgTag = document.getElementById("gear");
    var svgDoc = null;

    svgDoc = svgTag.getSVGDocument();
    alert(svgDoc);

}
```

and

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full">
<!-- http://www.mozilla.org/projects/svg/ -->
  <g id="gearG" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1cm">
    <circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" fill="red"
                    transform="translate(0,50)" />
    <circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" fill="blue"
                    transform="translate(70,150)" />
    <circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" fill="green"
                    transform="translate(-70,150)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out. I should put the "onload" at svg object tag rather than body tag. I guess in this case svgDoc can be defined when svg object is loaded.

```
 <object onload="RotateSVG()" id="gear"...
```

Try this(temporarily): http://ihome.ust.hk/~cs_lyfac/svgQuestion2/a.html

Yet firefox(4) works fine on both cases.

Comment: A good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337293/how-to-check-if-an-embedded-svg-document-is-loaded-in-an-html-page/3510578#3510578