# Select ChildElement from object tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I made a webpage that loads an svg with the object tag

```
<object id="svgContainer" type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

and want to display some content dynamically. When I include the svg direct inside the HTML it works fine

```
<svg id="svgVontainer">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="2" id="edit" />
</svg>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#edit").hide();
});
```

But when I try the same code with the `object` it doesn't work.

Does someone know that problem and how to fix it?

EDIT:
Here a jsFiddle so you can see what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/Ue7m7/.

Comment: It works for my side... See here : http://jsfiddle.net/db5d8/, comment hide line to show svg...

Comment: As I said, it is working if you use the svg tag. But I want to use the <object> tag

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle?

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/Ue7m7/

Comment: Your fiddle shows this error: `Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'webkitCreateShadowRoot' on 'Element': Author-created shadow roots are disabled for this element.`, when I removed svg and had only object in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to hide/show the SVG `object` tag, [you can do it as usual with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Ue7m7/2/).

But if you want to deal with the content of the 'remote' SVG `object`, this seems to be possible but with some restrictions:

- You need to have the SVG file in the same domain as your hosted page (due to the same security reasons as the `iframe` tag).
- To manipulate SVG `object` tags with JS you need to have extra JS code, as shown [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html). I think with jQuery you could try `$("#rect1").get(0).getSVGDocument()` or something similar (I haven't tested that snippet). [Check that link to learn more](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html).
- You have the possibility to include [SVG fallback](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) (if the SVG file can't be rendered).

Comment: Thank you so much, it wokred. (Later I'll post a JSFiddle with working code if someone gets the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try some vanilla instead

```
function hide(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
function show(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display === "none")
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
    else
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this code is not working. ```document.getElementById(id)``` is null

Comment: are you using '#edit' or 'edit'? should be hide('edit')

Comment: Yes I did so. I also used ```console.log(document.getElementById("id));``` to see what the result is.

Comment: `document.getElementById('svgContainer').style.display = "none"` I tried that on your <object> html and it worked? Just checked out your jsFiddle and its missing a rect1 id on a tag

Comment: @nepeo And what if he wants to hide only one of the rectangles?

Comment: the id values of the SVG file are not visible to JS, although i believe you can change the SVG to make them visible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566377/why-is-getelementbyid-failing-for-an-svg

Comment: Indeed I only want to hide a rectangle, not the whole <object> element.