# Having problems with changing image javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm new to JavaScript and am having problems with changing an image on my html document. I know that in order to change images, I need to change the    src attribute of the img.

I have an image called "magenta.jpg" that I want to replace with "fuschia.jpg" as soon as the page loads.

My HTML

```
<img src="magenta.jpg" name="photo" id="photo">
```

My JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("photo").src = "fuschia.jpg";
```

When I try doing this, I get an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Could you please help me understand what is going wrong with the code, and how to fix it?

Comment: Where is your script ? It must be executed after the DOM is ready. A solution is to put it at the end of the body.

Comment: It's a separate javascript file called "script.js". And I want it to remain this way for semantics.

Comment: If you include that file in the head section of your page, it's executed before there even is an element

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem now. But what should I do if I really want to keep a separate javascript file?

Comment: include the file right before the closing body tag

Answer (score 5):

It executed before DOM is loaded. To solve this you can either move the `<script>` to the bottom of the document or

Inside your .js file:
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("photo").src = "fuschia.jpg";
}
```

Or if you prefer [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#photo").attr("src", "fuschia.jpg");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be you execute your script before the element is in the DOM, hence the `null`.

If you want to keep the script in a separate file, you may call your code on load :

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("photo").src = "fuschia.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you include your external script in the head of your document, then the DOM won't be ready and your document.getElementById("photo") will return null.  Make sure you include the script just before the closing  tag (best practice for performance reasons).

```
<script src="yourfile.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/musicm122/ezav7/1/) is a working example of changing a photo that includes a happy baby.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/32/A_photo_of_an_8.5-week-old_baby_smiling.jpg/480px-A_photo_of_an_8.5-week-old_baby_smiling.jpg" name="photo" id="photo">
<input type="button" value="Click To Change" onclick="ChangePhoto();"/>
```

```
var ChangePhoto= function() {
    var newPicLocation = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Happy_face_ball.jpg";
    document.getElementById("photo").src = newPicLocation;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the element with id "photo". Presumably the element hasn't been loaded yet.

For more information about that check these questions:
[How to check if an embedded SVG document is loaded in an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337293/how-to-check-if-an-embedded-svg-document-is-loaded-in-an-html-page)
[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

or use jquery's $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code inested of your code, its work!

in html file

```
<div id="photo">
     <img src="magenta.jpg" name="photo">
</div>
```

and in javascript file

```
var temp= document.getElementById("photo");
temp.innerHTML=" <img name="photo" src='fuschia.jpg'>";
```