# How to know when an <embed> element's content has loaded

Tags: javascript, embed-tag

I'm programmatically adding an `<embed>` tag to my HTML document:

```
var e = document.createElement('embed');
e.src = "some-image.svg";
e.type = "image/svg+xml";
document.body.appendChild(e);
```

This works fine, and the SVG element displays as expected. However, I want to manipulate the SVG elements with JavaScript, and attempting to do so immediately after adding the element to the DOM fails, as the content hasn't loaded yet.

How can I do this. Note that I want to do this **without jQuery** so please don't point to the jQuery API.

Comment: What about `e.addEventListener("load", function() { ... })`?

Comment: have you assigned any id to embeded element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an embedded SVG document is loaded in an html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337293/how-to-check-if-an-embedded-svg-document-is-loaded-in-an-html-page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [@RGraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571194/rgraham) points out in a comment, the `<embed>` element raises the `load` event when its content is ready.

So my code becomes:

```
var e = document.createElement('embed');
e.src = "img/z-slider.svg";
e.type = "image/svg+xml";
document.body.appendChild(e);

e.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    // Operate upon the SVG DOM here
    e.getSVGDocument().querySelector('#some-node').textContent = "New text!";
});
```

This is better than polling as there is no flicker. The SVG is modified immediately upon load, before it is painted.

Comment: The event does not fire in Safari

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to the created element.

```
  function check_if_loaded() {
    var your_svg = document.getElementById("id").getSVGDocument();
    if (your_svg) {
        alert("loaded");

    } else {
        console.log("not yet loaded")
    }
}

your_element.addEventListener('load',check_if_loaded, false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do you think polling is needed? In my experimentation across Chrome/Firefox/IE when the `load` event fires, the SVG document is available.

Comment: Also, I don't need to add an `id` to the element as I already have a reference to it (`e` in my example.)

Comment: just a quick solution..yours is a better one.i will jst get rid of the polling part

Comment: Further, `clear_me_later` is private to the event callback function, so the call to `clearInterval` won't work.