# Change svg element only works some of the times

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to use javascript and html5 to create a HMI for a project.
In this first experiment i just want to change a text element in the svg document.

The svg object is defined in html like this:

```
<object id="image-svg" width="800" height="800" type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>
```

This script:

```
function update_txtPv( val )
{
    var imageSvgDoc = document.getElementById( "image-svg" ).contentDocument;
    var txtPv = imageSvgDoc.getElementById( "txtPv" );
    txtPv.textContent = val;
}

update_txtPv( "test" );
```

gets called once when the page loads.

Problem is that if I refresh the page ten times it only sets the text object to "test" about three of the times.

if I add an alert( "something" ); in the beginning of the function it works.

What is going on?

//John

Comment: Be sure your svg got loaded (`document.getElementById( "image-svg" ).addEventListener('load',function(){update_txtPv( "test" );});`) + look in your js console for errors thrown.

Comment: @Kaiido That makes sense. But I still get "TypeError: imageSvgDoc is null" some of the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... it turned out that i needed to wait for the svg document to load before starting to alter it.

Ended up using a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337293/how-to-check-if-an-embedded-svg-document-is-loaded-in-an-html-page) thread. Big thanks to Kaiido for pointing out that I need to wait for the svg to finish loading before calling the function.